# How to set a checkbox to "checked" using mshtml?

Tags: c#, .net, html, webforms, mshtml

I can do most things I need to with mshtml, but I'm a bit stuck with how to set a checkbox input element to "checked". Here's the situation...

```
IHTMLElementCollection inputElements = (IHTMLElementCollection)doc.all.tags("input");
foreach (IHTMLElement el in inputElements)
{
    string elementHtml = el.outerHTML;
    string termsOfServiceIdentifier = "id=chkUTOS_ver2";

    //  select the Terms of Service checkbox
    if (elementHtml.Contains(termsOfServiceIdentifier)) 
    {
        HTMLInputElement chkTOS = (HTMLInputElement)el;
        chkTOS.@checked = true;  //  that's the solution. Thanks Wayne.
     }
     else
     {
        //  do nothing - we're not interested in this element
     }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Gregg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[HTMLInputElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347093(VS.85).aspx) exposes the Checked property as a Boolean

Comment: I must have messed something up before, 'cause it wasn't in Intellisense. Now it sure is. Cheers Wayne!

Comment: I just tried and found I had to use @checked from C# for it to complile. [checked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

In plain JavaScript, checkbox elements have a `checked` property. So [in plain JavaScript] you might write:

```
document.getElementById("myCheckbox").checked = true;
```

I don't know .NET or whatever you're using there, but they may do it in a similar way.

Steve

Comment: Thanks for the help. BTW It's C#.